# How to get notified when a redis key expired?

Tags: node.js, redis

Why can't get notified when a key expired with the following code?

I want to use redis, and when a key is expired then notify me. Then i can do something.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis')
var sub = new Redis()
var pub = new Redis()

var subKey = '__keyevent@0__:del'

sub.subscribe(subKey, function () {
  console.log('subscribe success !')
})

sub.on('message', function (channel, message) {
  console.log(channel, message, '======')
})

var testKey = 'test'
setTimeout(function () {
  pub.multi()
      .set(testKey, 'test redis notify')
      .expire(testKey, 5)
      .exec(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err, 'why err ?')
          return
        }
        console.log('.....')
      })
}, 2000)
```

Comment: var subKey = '__keyevent@0__:expired'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove any non-constructive content. Please edit in to provide what exactly your code sample is doing. Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need server-side support for keyspace notification.

```
redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events KEA
```

After set, you may run bellow command to check:

```
redis-cli config get notify-keyspace-events
```

If you got message like:

```
1) "notify-keyspace-events"
2) "AKE"
```

Then, you can run your code and get what you want.

Further more, pay attention to [timing-of-expired-events](http://redis.io/topics/notifications#timing-of-expired-events).

Answer (score 1):

pre-requisite : you need to enable  key-space notification by entering the below line in redis.conf. or you can enable it temproraly as answered above by "sel-fish".

Now, the code inside your setTimeout block fire these events :

1. **keyspace@0**:test  ======
2. **keyevent@0**:set  ======
3. **keyspace@0**:test  ======
4. **keyevent@0**:expire  ======
5. **keyspace@0**:test  ======
6. **keyevent@0**:expired  ======

as you can see it actually never fire del event. So that is the reason you are not getting notification.

so you need to subscribe to keyevent@0:expired channel.